# One string, two rawurlencode outputs

Tags: php, urlencode, server

I have one string, but two types of rawurlencode outputs.
String:

```
Ďalšia skúšková písomka 2009.jpg
```

rawurlencode output on my hosting server:

```
D%CC%8Cals%CC%8Cia%20sku%CC%81s%CC%8Ckova%CC%81%20pi%CC%81somka%202009.jpg
```

Output from [this](https://www.functions-online.com/rawurlencode.html) server:

```
%C4%8Eal%C5%A1ia%20sk%C3%BA%C5%A1kov%C3%A1%20p%C3%ADsomka%202009.jpg
```

Why there are differences? I want same output on my server too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) page:

> 5.3.4     Tilde characters are no longer encoded when rawurlencode() is used with EBCDIC strings.

So it sounds like you are running different versions of PHP on your servers. One is older than 5.3.4. You'd better upgrade it if you want the output to be the same.

Comment: I checked my hosting php version and it is 5.5 So this another server is running older version. Problem is that I need older one version of urlencode.